# Подключение inline кнопок в tg боте к БД sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на inline кнопку, именно она сама сохранялась в базу данных sqlite3. Вот пример кода телеграм бота.
Мне нужно, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку, допустим, "хлеб" она добавлялась в базу данных. Это бот-магазин. Читал про sqlite3 но не понял как подключать ее к кнопкам. (python, aiogram)
Прописал все как в ответе, но с условием намудрил, наверное. Мне нужно добавить кнопку получается при нажатии это callback_data='bread_1'

```
bread = InlineKeyboardButton('Хлеб', callback_data='bread')
butt = InlineKeyboardButton('Масло', callback_data='netflix_kb')
muca = InlineKeyboardButton('Мука', callback_data='youtube_kb')
back = InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='back')
inline_kb1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(bread, butt, muca)
inline_kb1.add(back)
inline_kb2 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(bread, butt, muca)
inline_kb2.add(back)
bread_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Купить', callback_data='bread_1')
spoti_back = InlineKeyboardButton('Назад ', callback_data='spoti_back')
spotify_back = InlineKeyboardButton('Назад ко всем категориям', callback_data='spotify_back')
spotitime_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
spotitime_kb.add(bread_1)
spotitime_kb.add(spoti_back)
spotitime_kb.add(spotify_back)
sp_ot = InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='sp_ot')
sp_back = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(sp_ot)
```

Условие для отлова кнопки и добавления в БД

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="bread_1")
async def buy_me(message: types.CallbackQuery):
    await datdb.db.add(bread_1)
    import sqlite3
```

```
Файл БД.
```

```
class datdb():
    #__init__ запускается каждый раз при вызове класа или его екземпляра
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('skittle.db')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    
    def add(self, buys_me, buy_1):
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO skittle.db (buys_me, buy_1) VALUES (?, ?)", (buys_me, buy_1,))
        self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: Эмм, вы хотите хранить КНОПКУ в бд? Или я неправильно понял? Что значит "подключить"?

Comment: Именно как надпись кнопки, тоесть хлеб.  Хлеб после нажатия должен уходить в БД. Так же и с др. Не сама кнопка улетает, а продукт

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант создать еще один питон файл с классом для взаемодействия с базой данных

### sklitedb.py

```
import sqlite3
class db():
    #__init__ запускается каждый раз при вызове класа или его екземпляра
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('ваша база.db')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    
    def add():
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (Сюда название столбцов в которые вводим данные) VALUES (?  Знаков вопроса вводим столько сколько столбцов)", (Сюда переменные,)
        self.conn.commit()
```

Импортируем клас и теперь пишем декоратор `callback_query_handler` и в нем вызивает `sklitedb.db.add()`
Подробнее о работе с sqlite3 в документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

### Новое

Вместо `text='bread_1'` вставте `lambda call: call.data =='bread`

Comment: Вставил код, исправил все под свой код, но проблема не ушла.